# Facebook FB.ui SDK function not working properly in I.E

Tags: javascript, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm currently using this code in one of my FB Apps:

```
FB.ui({
       method: 'permissions.request',
       perms: 'user_website,email',
       display: 'popup'
       },function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        if (response && response.perms) {
           FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            });
        } else if (!response.perms) {
        }
    }
});
```

Which ask user to login and authorize the application with a dialog box. The dialog cancel and allow buttons work fine in all browser but in IE. When I click on cancel or allow buttons the dialog box does not disappear (i.e dialog box stuck out).

Comment: Hello Naresh.... did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to faceook :

XFBML substantially improves the performance of social plugins in Internet Explorer and also reduces some known issues (see FB.init for more details). In order to use XFBML on your webpage, you must add an XML namespace attribute to the root  element of your page. Without this declaration, XFBML tags will not render in Internet Explorer.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

do you have your html tag formated as above..??

Comment: Hi, I have already use xml namespace attribute in html tag. but permission dialog box still stucked in I.E 9.